# Seg Fault on memset

Tags: c

I'm trying to grow an array to add newly malloc'd pointers.  The realloc doesn't seem to be increasing the size.  Also, I start with enough space for one pointer in the array, so even though the realloc didn't increase the size, I still expected to be able to copy a pointer in, but I get a SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault.

```
typedef struct active_allocation {
    size_t sz;
    void *ptr;
} ACTIVE_ALLOCATION;

struct m61_state {
    ACTIVE_ALLOCATION **active_allocations_ptrs_arr; //Array of Points to Active Allocations
    size_t sz;
};
struct m61_state m61_state;
...
ACTIVE_ALLOCATION **active_allocations_ptrs_arr = malloc(sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*) *1); 
m61_state.active_allocations_ptrs_arr = active_allocations_ptrs_arr;
...
//Create a New pointer, to add to the array
ACTIVE_ALLOCATION *active_allocation_record = malloc(sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION));

// ** Initially there's space for one pointer, but it hasn't been used yet.  
//m61_state->sz equals 0.
//Trying to increase the size of an array to 8 for one more ACTIVE_ALLOCATION* Last 4 can be set to NULl
//sizeof(new_active_alloc_array_ptr) equals 4 at this point
new_active_alloc_array_ptr = realloc(m61_state->active_allocations_ptrs_arr, m61_state->sz + sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*));

//** sizeof(new_active_alloc_array_ptr) still equals 4.  I want it to be 8. I'm not sure why the size didn't change.

//Copy the new pointer that was just created active_allocation_record to the array
memset(m61_state->active_allocations_ptrs_arr[sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)* m61_state->sz], (int)active_allocation_record, sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*));
```

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: `sizeof(new_active_alloc_array_ptr)` is the size of a pointer. It will never change.

Comment: If you find yourself using `memset` to "copy" data, you are Doing It Wrong™.  That's what `memcpy` (or simple assignment!) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would expect the size of `new_active_alloc_array_ptr` to change, it is a pointer and will always have the same size - the size of a pointer.

There's a number of errors all of which could be causing your crash:

(1) You're re-sizing to `m61_state->sz + sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)` when it seems like you want enough space for `m61_state->sz` entries of size `sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)` so it should be `m61_state->sz * sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)`.

(2) You appear to be storing the realloc'd pointer to a temporary (`new_active_alloc_array_ptr`) and then accessing the original `m61_state->active_allocations_ptrs_arr` value.

(3) When you access the array you're accessing elements as `[sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)* m61_state->sz]` - there is no call for the `sizeof(ACTIVE_ALLOCATION*)*` here, it should be `[m61_state->sz]`.

(4) Elements in an array of size `n` are accessed from `0` to `n-1` so even if you'd allocated correctly to create an array of size `m61_state->sz` then `[m61_state->sz]` would still point to an element one beyond the end of the space you've allocated.

Comment: Also, it looks like he's trying to copy a pointer using `memset`, which is wrong on several levels.